# Como incluir todas as minhas páginas dentro de uma só?

Tags: php, loop, while, include

estou desenvolvendo um sistema onde quero que na página "cardápio" seja incluído todas as minhas categorias, que já tem um layout próprio em sua página, para isso estou tentando usar o while loop desse jeito:

```
<section class="pages">
    
    <?php 
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM dados_categoria WHERE ativo='S'");
        $stmt->execute();
        $resultado = $stmt->get_result();
            while($rows = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
    
        echo '<div class="page-card">
                <h1 class="title">'.$rows['nome_categoria'].'</h1>
                '.include('pages/'.$rows['categoria'].'.php').'
            </div>';
    
        }
    ?>
    </section>
```

Infelizmente dessa maneira o site não carrega as páginas com o "include" e está apresentando o seguinte:

```
Warning: include(pages/pizza.php </div>): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\foodOrderSystem\pages\cardapio.php on line 11

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'pages/pizza.php </div>' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\foodOrderSystem\pages\cardapio.php on line 11
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posso estar errado mas acho que seu erro está aqui:

```
echo '<div class="page-card">
   <h1 class="title">'.$rows['nome_categoria'].'</h1>
   '.include('pages/'.$rows['categoria'].'.php').'
</div>';
```

Tente mudar para:

```
echo '<div class="page-card">';
   echo '<h1 class="title">'.$rows['nome_categoria'].'</h1>';
   include('pages/'.$rows['categoria'].'.php');
echo '</div>';
```

Certifique-se que os arquivos com o mesmo nome da categoria exitam dentro da pasta.

Comment: Funcionou, dessa forma não da mais erro, entretanto ele só ta chamando 1 vez, quando era pra chamar 3 divs com 3 includes diferentes, como se o loop não estivesse funcionando, consegue imaginar qual seja a causa?

Comment: detalhe quando eu tiro o include do meio do código ele chama corretamente as 3 div's verifiquei e o diretorio e nome dos arquivos estão corretos, pois utilizo esse método de include em outra página desse mesmo projeto com base em informações do banco de dados, entretanto é um include único, ou seja só uma página sem ter um loop chamando várias páginas em uma só.

Comment: Após dar uma olhada no código logo percebi o motivo de executar o include apenas uma vez... Na minha pagina "pizza" por exemplo, existe uma query para pegar os dados do banco de dados, com isso quando eu chamo o include ele inclui esses dados do banco de dados substituindo minha query anterior da pagina cardapio, por conta disso o loop se encerra ali...

Comment: No caso do `include()`, entre outras funções nativas do PHP não é possível fazer a concatenação com elas, como foi na sua questão. Sobre a quebra do seu loop eu ia responder antes mas não deu, você conseguiu achar o problema. Eu geralmente nomeio as consultas com variáveis exclusivas, algo mais ou menos assim `$sel_categoria` `$sel_cardapio`

Answer (score -1):

A resposta do amigo resolveu meu problema, entretanto como comentei o include estava me gerando conflito encerrando o meu loop while. Após analizar descobri que o problema eram duas variáveis iguais no meu cardapio e na página do include com valores diferentes.

Código antes:

```
<?php 
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM dados_categoria WHERE ativo='S'");
$stmt->execute();
$resultado = $stmt->get_result();
while($rows = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
    echo '<div class="page-card">';
    echo '<h1 class="title">'.$rows['nome_categoria'].'</h1>';
    include('pages/'.$rows['categoria'].'.php');
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Código depois:

```
<?php 
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM dados_categoria WHERE ativo='S'");
$stmt->execute();
$resultante = $stmt->get_result();
while($cat = $resultante->fetch_assoc()){
    echo '<div class="page-card">';
    echo '<h1 class="title">'.$cat['nome_categoria'].'</h1>';
    include('pages/'.$cat['categoria'].'.php');
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```